# Image under toggle navigation gets pushed down

Tags: jquery, html, toggle, navbar

I've got a toggle navigation and an additional navigation bar.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="navbar">
   <li>Nav1</li>
   <li>Nav2</li>
</ul>

<ul class="navbar-additional">
 <li>Nav3</li>
 <li>Nav4</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
navbar-additional{
   list-style-type: none;
   position: absolute;
   top: 189px;
   left: 458px;
}
```

**JS**

```
var $menu = $('ul.navbar');

$menu.transition({top: -$menu.height() - parseInt($menu.css('padding-top')) - parseInt($menu.css('padding-bottom')), duration: 300});
```

The navigation with class navbar is the navigation that toggles, but the second navigation slides down and needs to stay at the same place. How can I freeze the position of the navbar additional?

Comment: can you post your code in a http://jsfiddle.net You can probally try giving your nav bar: position: fixed;

Comment: position: fixed; worked, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your nav bar:

```
position: fixed;
```

In your css code.

This should solve your problem!